# How can I add a GUI to my program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

After reading and learning from online tutorials. I now know the fundamentals of python. However I am tired of just making interactive text-based program. I want an interface for my program, to be specific I want a graphical user interface for my program. How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a GUI (Graphical User Interface). You can check the list of GUI's available for Python [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming), along with their commentary. You can pick whichever you feel is the closest to what you want, and start learning by reading their documentaries and practicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tkinter or pygtk using glade which I recommend. Check this http://www.pygtk.org/tutorial.html